# Access ui-router resolve in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I continue to discover the great ui-router. I'm focusing now on `resolve()`functions. I have a base `$state`where I'm resolving a query() from the backend.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('baseApp', {
      url: '/app',
      abstract: false,
      templateUrl: 'app/layout/baseApp.html',
      authenticate: true,
      resolve: {
        // Access API Service
        APIService: 'APIService',

        // Operators
        myObjects: function(APIService){
          // APIService is a service exposing $resource
          return APIService.myObjects.query().$promise;
        }
      }
    })
    .state('baseApp.state1', {
      url: '/state1',
      views: {
        'workspace':  {
          templateUrl: 'app/state1.html',
          controller: 'State1Ctrl',
          controllerAs: 'state1'
        }
      },
      authenticate: true
    })
```

I'm trying to access `myObjects` in my `State1Ctrl`:

```
function State1Ctrl(myObjects) {
    ....
    console.log(myObjects);
    ....
}
```

I was hoping to see myMobject list printing in the console. Sadly, here is the ouput :

```
undefined
```

It seems I am not able to access the promise in my controller. Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: That code looks OK to me.  Can you put this minimal example in a plunkr?  Side note: APIService: 'APIService' is unnecessary...

Answer (score 0):

You should get data in `$resource` promise then function.

```
function State1Ctrl(myObjects) {
    ....
    cmyObjects.then(function(data){
         console.log(data)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually simple :

ui-router inject resolve values to the controller associated to the state.

To get it into your controller you should move your resolve to the sub-state

```
$stateProvider
.state('baseApp', {
  url: '/app',
  abstract: false,
  templateUrl: 'app/layout/baseApp.html',
  authenticate: true
})
.state('baseApp.state1', {
  url: '/state1',
  views: {
    'workspace':  {
     resolve: {
        // Access API Service
        APIService: 'APIService',

        // Operators
        myObjects: function(APIService){
          // APIService is a service exposing $resource
          return APIService.myObjects.query().$promise;
        }    
      }
      templateUrl: 'app/state1.html',
      controller: 'State1Ctrl',
      controllerAs: 'state1'
    }
  },
  authenticate: true
})
```

EDIT : In your specific case i feel that what you want is to have a "parent" controller into your first state like this :

```
$stateProvider
.state('baseApp', {
  url: '/app',
  abstract: false,
  templateUrl: 'app/layout/baseApp.html',
  authenticate: true,
  controller: BaseAppCtrl,
  resolve: {
    // Access API Service
    APIService: 'APIService',

    // Operators
    myObjects: function(APIService){
      // APIService is a service exposing $resource
      return APIService.myObjects.query().$promise;
    }
  }
})
.state('baseApp.state1', {
  url: '/state1',
  views: {
    'workspace':  {
      templateUrl: 'app/state1.html',
      controller: 'State1Ctrl',
      controllerAs: 'state1'
    }
  },
  authenticate: true
})
```

You will just have to inject theses parameters into the parent controller. You can access the parent $scope within your child $scope.

In the parent controller :

```
function BaseAppCtrl($scope, myObjects) {
    ....
    $scope.myObjects = myObjects;
    console.log(myObjects);
    ....
}

function State1Ctrl($scope) {
    ....
    console.log($scope.myObjects);
    ....
}
```

Both console.log should display the value in this case.

You can see it working on [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rYZZubRNTmVga2but3Be?p=preview)

Hope it helped.

Comment: I tried to add a parent controller and to access the resolved myObjects, but I still have undefined as result.

Comment: Gonna make a plunker to validate my guesses. I'll share it

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to apply this method http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-application-wide-resources-centrally-in-angularjs-with-ui-router/ to access resources globally.

Comment: To access resources globally i usually only works with services. You can get an exemple at https://github.com/Okazari/MyVirtualStoryBook/blob/master/app/feature/common/service/PlayerService.js where i store the players books for all my application into a service. I don't have enough time to provide the plunker, i'll come back to it later.

Comment: @AlexGrs here is a plunker validating my guesses. http://plnkr.co/edit/rYZZubRNTmVga2but3Be?p=preview I just spotted something that may be your issue. Did you try to return APIService.myObjects.query() instead of APIService.myObjects.query().$promise ?

Comment: Nope I'm trying to return a$promise but it doesn't work. Your example works perfectly. But in my app, it doesn't... still undefined.... I went to using services to manage this.